# I cant UPDATE datetime to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help.
I'm try to UPDATE a datetime to MySQL, but it didn't work.

The declaration is like this:

```
    $startDate = time();
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+7 days', $startDate));
```

After this i want to UPDATE, but in MySQL is still blank always.

UPDATE:

```
mtquery("UPDATE table SET end_time = ".$time." WHERE id = ".$table['id']."");
```

If i use NOW() instead of ".$time.", it works perfectly.

If someone can help, please write the solution.

Thanks,

KoLi

Comment: wrap time variable in quotes

Comment: Ohh God! I cant believe this. Thank You, it works! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of PHP time(), you can use MySQL date time functions

You can use MySQL query as

```
UPDATE table SET end_time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) WHERE id = "'".$table['id']."'"
```